# filter on new updated queryset return empty queryset using ORM Django

Tags: python, django, orm

when looping the `queryset` and update field in the model using `save()` function, then try to filter on the updated queryset , the filter result returns empty even the there are still elements in the queryset that achieve the condition.

please check the code below.

```
qs = queryset.filter(status=models.BankTransfer.STATUS_NEW)
for bank_transfer in qs:
     bank_transfer.status = models.BankTransfer.STATUS_APPROVED
     bank_transfer.save()
```

Btw when I print `qs`, it returns with results, but I try to get the first object by using `first()`, it returns None

```
for bank_transfer in qs.filter(purpose__status='pending_completed'):
     bank_transfer.purpose.status = 'completed'
     bank_transfer.purpose.save()
```

Banktransfer Model:

```
class BankTransfer(models.Model):
        swift_code = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, verbose_name=_('SWIFT'))
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        amount = models.DecimalField(blank=False, default=D('0'), max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, verbose_name=_('Amount'))
        purpose = models.ForeignKey('auction.Purpose', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name=_('Status'))
```

Purpose Model:

```
class Purpose(models.Model):
          status = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name=_('Status'))
          bla 
          bla
```

Comment: You set all items status from `STATUS_NEW` to `STATUS_APPROVED`, hence when you do `qs.filter(..)` it is emtpy, since there are no items anymore with `STATUS_NEW`.

Comment: Can you share the relevant models (likely the `BankTransfer`, and the `Purpose` model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sure one min

Comment: I added the models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qs` is `QuerySet` with items that have as `status` `STATUS_NEW`. In the first loop, you update all these items such that they have `STATUS_APPROVED`.

But a `QuerySet` is essentially a query that you are constructing. If you call `qs.filter(purpose__status='pending_completed')`, then you make a *new* query and you look for items that have as `status=STATUS_NEW` *and* with a `purpose__status` being equal to `pending_completed`, which does not make much sense.

You thus should process the querysets in the opposite way:

```
qs = queryset.filter(status=models.BankTransfer.STATUS_NEW)
for bank_transfer in qs.filter(purpose__status='pending_completed'):
    purpose = bank_transfer.purpose
    purpose.status = 'completed'
    purpose.save()

for bank_transfer in qs:
     bank_transfer.status = models.BankTransfer.STATUS_APPROVED
     bank_transfer.save()
```

We can do the updates in bulk however to boost efficiency:

```
qs = queryset.filter(status=models.BankTransfer.STATUS_NEW)
Purpose.objects.filter(
    bank_transfer__in=qs,
    status='pending_completed'
).update(status='completed')

qs.update(
    status=models.BankTransfer.STATUS_APPROVED
)
```

this updates the tables in bulk, so without enumerating over the objects in the Django/Python layer, but with an `UPDATE …` query.

Comment: Thank u willem you're always helpful to the whole community.
I supposed that I preserved a variable with results of queryset then i can make a quey on that results but that was false